# Where can I find a compilation of After the Bomb material?

Tags: after-the-bomb

I'm looking into hosting a game in the After the Bomb campaign setting, as I played in one before and it was really a lot of fun, however I'm having issues finding all the resources needed to run the game, as well as a lot of information on how to create characters, what system the game runs on, and a myriad of other things that aren't covered in the small book that is the campaign setting. Can anyone elaborate on these things?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/After_the_Bomb_%28game%29 this seems to contain the information on what system the game runs on, but I don't believe we can legally provide rules or links to rules on stackexchange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the Bomb is a setting of Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles by Palladium, [available for purchase](https://palladium-store.com/1001/category/After-the-Bomb.html).